# JSF does not convert InputText value to string variable of backing bean without custom converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

I try learn JSF and faced with problem. 
I did use Servlet 2.5, JDK 1.6 and JSF 2.0.6 (com.sun.faces version from pom file).

I have a simple JSF page that has a `<h:inputText/>` tag for interaction with user

I expect what user fill this `h:inputText` then click on `h:commandButton` and on server side i will get backing bean with updated value.

But in my case lifecycle of JSF breaks on `process validations`, move to `render 
response` and show to user "Parser error!" message

I.e. for simple `h:inputText` without any validator and converter i receive error message from server side about parsing of `h:inputText` value.

After some time i figured out what i can create my own converter which will not modify object, just pass `String` through himself.

I did add my realization of converter to `<h:inputText/>` and this work.

Question: 
In all examples in books and other tutorials nobody used custom converter for `<h:inputText/>` if `inputText` is representation of `String` value of backing bean. 
Why all of this tutorials and examples not working for me without custom converter? Where my mistake?

Source codes: 
**index.xhtml** without converter, not worked for me:

```
<h:form id="UserForm">
    <h:outputText value="Insert your first name:" />
    <h:inputText id="userNameID" required="true" value="#{userBean.firstName}">
        <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="25" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false" for="userNameID" />

    <h:commandButton id="submit" action="/view/validator/response?faces-redirect=true"
        value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

**UserBean.java**:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

**MyConverter.java** - dummy converter

```
@FacesConverter(value = "myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
         return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml** with converter, worked as expected:

```
<h:form id="UserForm">
    <h:outputText value="Insert your first name:" />
    <h:inputText id="userNameID" required="true" value="#{userBean.firstName}" converter="myConverter">
        <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="25" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false" for="userNameID" />

    <h:commandButton id="submit" action="/view/validator/response?faces-redirect=true"
        value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: You're not running the code you think you're running. The error is coming from a different converter which is not visible in the information provided so far. Perhaps you've created a `@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)` which thus automatically runs on every single `String` property?

Comment: BalusC, thanks for answer. You are right. I have message in `sys.out` "detail=(Cannot parse this date!)" and one `DateConverter` from another lesson. After change in `DateConverter` from `@FacesConverter` to `@FacesConverter(value = "dateConverter")` all works as expect. But why this converter was applied to `inputText` without any converters?

Comment: Because of the `forClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is not visible in the code posted so far, but the key symptom *"it fails with a message coming from a so far unidentified converter while it succeeds with an explicit converter"* suggests that you've elsewhere in the same project a `@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)` which would run automatically on every single `String` property which doesn't have another converter explicitly specified.

Comment: I did not have any `forClass` converters but your suggestion has helped me

Comment: If you don't specify any explicit converter name or class like so `@FacesConverter public class FooConverter {}`, then it defaults to `String` class and thus get applied on every single `String` input which doesn't have an explicit converter.